# _hasOnlyFixColumnWidths is not a function in TableTree in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5, xmltable, treetable

I created a tree table month ago and it worked fine without issue. But recently it doesn't work because of following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t._hasOnlyFixColumnWidths is not a function
at Object.b.renderTableControlCnt (TableRenderer.js?eval:formatted:623)
at Object.b.renderTableControl (TableRenderer.js?eval:formatted:539)
at Object.b.renderTableCtrl (TableRenderer.js?eval:formatted:520)
at Object.b.renderTableCCnt (TableRenderer.js?eval:formatted:171)
at Object.b.renderTable (TableRenderer.js?eval:formatted:163)
at Object.b.render (TableRenderer.js?eval:formatted:78)
at Object.R.renderControl (RenderManager-dbg.js:422)
at Object.a.render (library-preload.js?eval:3495)
at Object.R.renderControl (RenderManager-dbg.js:422)
at d.S.render (library-preload.js?eval:6304)
```

in the debugger it seems the function "_hasOnlyFixColumnWidths" doesn't exist. There is no attribute or function available on sap.ui.table.Table or sap.ui.table.TreeTable.

The relevent controller codes:

I am not sure how this error was triggered. In the debugger this error is not triggered by my code. Perhaps it occurs during rendering tree table.

My tree table is defined in the XML view, and I bind rows in the controller class:

```
// build odata model
that.aTreeData = data;
var oTreeModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({treeData: that.aTreeData});

var oTree = that.getView().byId("idTreeTable");
oTree.setModel(oTreeModel);
oTree.bindRows({
      path: "/treeData",
  parameters: {
    countMode: "Inline"
  }
```

and the relevant xml file:

```
    <table:TreeTable
    id="idTreeTable"
    width="100%"
    selectionMode="sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.None"
    enableColumnReordering="false"
    expandFirstLevel="false"
    >
    <table:columns>
        <table:Column lable="{i18n>columnDescription}" width="20rem">
            <!--<Label text="{i18n>columnDescription}"/>-->
            <table:template>
                <Text text="{desc}"/>
            </table:template>
        </table:Column>
        <table:Column>
            <!--<Label text="{i18n>columnRequestId}"/>-->
            <table:template>
                <Text text="{nodeId}"/>
            </table:template>
        </table:Column>
        <table:Column>
            <!--<Label text="{i18n>columnProduct}"/>-->
            <table:template>
                <Text text="{product}"/>
            </table:template>
        </table:Column>
        <table:Column>
            <!--<Label text="{i18n>columnGrossWeight}"/>-->
            <table:template>
                <ObjectNumber
                    number="{grossWeight}"
                    unit="{weightUnit}"/>
            </table:template>
        </table:Column>
        <table:Column>
            <!--<Label text="{i18n>columnConsumedGrossWeight}"/>-->
            <table:template>
                <Input 
                    id="inputWeight"
                    type="Number"
                    value="{consumedGrossWeight}"
                    enabled="{editEnable}"/>
            </table:template>
        </table:Column>
    </table:columns>
</table:TreeTable>
```

it seems the typeError message is only reported when I launch the application in **Chrome**.

It works fine in **IE** or **Firefox**. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: The method _hasOnlyFixColumnWidths appears to be a private method used internally by UI5 and may not be a part of the documentation. Please share some code which triggers this error.

Comment: Thank you Stephen!
I am not sure how this error was triggered. In the debugger this error is not triggered by my code. Perhaps it occurs during rendering tree table.

My tree table is defined in the XML view, and I bind rows in the controller class:

Comment: Could you share the XML code used for creating the tree?

Comment: You seem to miss a closing tag in you code for <table:Column> in your Table's first Column. Can you confirm if this is not one of the reasons ?

Comment: Sorry for misleading! The xml code is correct. Otherwise the IDE will prompt the syntax check message.

Comment: it seems the typeError message is only reported when I launch the application in Chrome.

It works fine in IE or Firefox. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Seems to work in Chrome with the latest version of UI5 & Chrome. Which version do you use ?

Comment: Also a typo in : lable="{i18n>columnDescription}" in your first Column. Should be "label". Unlikely to be a problem, but you never can tell

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen! It is so weird and it works fine now in Chrome. I have no idea what happens on this and I didn't update Chrome recently.